# Explaining phase shift from a half-silvered mirror

Tags: optics, waves, reflection

I am trying to understand why light undergoes a phase shift when reflecting off one side of a half-silvered mirror, but not the other side.

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%E2%80%93Zehnder_interferometer#How_it_works) and this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/316573) both give the following explanation:

- According to the Fresnel equations, a wave:

  - Undergoes a phase shift of π when reflecting off the boundary with a denser medium.
  - Does not undergo any phase shift when reflecting off the boundary with a less dense medium.
- When light approaches the silvered side of a half-silvered mirror and reflects off the air-to-glass boundary, it will undergo a phase shift (because glass is more optically dense than air).
- When light approaches the non-silvered side of a half-silvered mirror, enters the glass and then reflects off the glass-to-air boundary, it will not undergo a phase shift (because air is less optically dense than glass).

However, this explanation seems to completely neglect the silver coating. It seems to me that there is no air-glass boundary at all, but instead an air-silver boundary and a silver-glass boundary.

What am I missing?

Comment: Related [Refractive index of mirror.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434283/refractive-index-of-mirror)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/330656 there is, ideally a 180 degree shift when reflecting from a metal surface.

Comment: @boyfarrell Then why is there no phase shift for light approaching from the non-silvered side of the mirror? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: Diagram would help this question get a good answer

Comment: Who says there would be no phase shift from the non-silvered side? It's just that very little light will be reflected at the interface between air and the not-silvered-side-of-the-glass. So approaching from the non-silvered side, you'd get a small fraction of the light reflected from the air-glass interface with a phase shift of pi, most of the light would enter the glass.

Comment: This is a good question, and nothing I've read here so far even tries to address it.  I'd address it if it weren't a holiday.  :-(

Answer (score -1):

With [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length#Lasers) light from a laser one can assume that the path lengths of a [Michelson interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_interferometer) are equal (for the purpose of your question) and due to the narrow bandwidth of the laser light one can also assume [low dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_interferometer#Source_bandwidth) (equal path lengths through the glass).

With everything assumed to be equal the only difference between the two paths that the light travels is:

There is a [phase change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%E2%80%93Zehnder_interferometer#Properties) for a reflection when a wave propagating in a lower-refractive index medium reflects from a higher-refractive index medium, but not in the opposite case.

[image: Michelson interferometer fringe formation]

Notice that the light travels through the glass twice, once from air to glass to mirror, and once from mirror to glass to air; one direction has increasing index and the other doesn't.

Reference:

"[Phase shift between the transmitted and the reflected optical fields of a semireflecting lossless mirror is π/2](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.12238)" (1980), by Vittorio Degiorgio, in the American Journal of Physics 48, 81 (1980); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.12238

Assuming a lossless beamsplitter the energy conservation condition $\left | E_0 \right |^2 = \left | E_t \right |^2 + \left | E_r \right |^2$ gives $\phi^{'}_t - \phi^{''}_t = \phi^{'}_r - \phi^{'}_r + \pi$, thus:

$$\phi_R = \phi_T + \pi / 2$$