# Phase difference in Michelson Interferometer

Tags: optics, visible-light, speed-of-light, interferometry, phase-velocity

I'm currently taking a quantum mechanics course in university and our professor introduced us to the Michelson Interferometer (or at least what I believe is an apparatus based on it), where a light beam is incident on a 50/50 beam splitter. I've drawn the following diagram to show what happens according to our professor. In the diagram, I've drawn the incoming light as having 2 parts so that it's easier to track it when it splits and recombines. The darker colors are the incident rays and the lighter colors are the reflected rays:
[image]

Our professor has claimed that if the phase difference between the "red" and "blue" light is $\pi$, then none of the light will go out the bottom and all of it will go out the left. I'm having trouble understanding this, though. I've shown my calculations below, calling the bottom "A" and the left output "B", using $\varphi$ for phase, and calling the initial distance $d_0$:
$$\varphi_{A,blue}=d_0+2d_1$$
$$\varphi_{A,red}=d_0+2d_2$$
$$\Delta \varphi_{A}=d_0+2d_1 - d_0 - 2d_2 = 2(d_2-d_1)$$
Let's say $d_1=d_2-\frac{\pi}{2}$:
$$\Delta \varphi_{A}=2(d_2-d_2+\frac{\pi}{2})=\pi$$
This means the light rays are $\pi$ phase apart coming out at the bottom, and will destructively interfere.

However, what's to stop us from using identical logic for B:

$$\varphi_{B,blue}=d_0+2d_1$$
$$\varphi_{B,red}=d_0+2d_2$$
$$\Delta \varphi_{B}=d_0+2d_1 - d_0 - 2d_2 = 2(d_2-d_1)$$
$$\Delta \varphi_{B}=2(d_2-d_2+\frac{\pi}{2})=\pi$$

This doesn't lead to the conclusion that we'll only see light coming out of B, which my professor claimed. This leads us to conclude that no light will come out. Can anyone please help reconcile this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing ingredient (seemingly omitted in lecture) is the phase applied by the beam splitter. If you check the Wikipedia entry on [beam splitters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter#Classical_lossless_beam_splitter), for example, it says that some beam splitters correspond to input/output matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}/\sqrt{2},$$ which would add a phase of $\pi$ to the component of the second path's output beam that comes from the second path's input beam, while others correspond to
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&i\\i&1\end{pmatrix}/\sqrt{2},$$ which adds a phase of $\pi/2$ to the component of the second path's output beam that comes from the first path's input beam and adds a phase of $\pi/2$ to the component of the first path's output beam that comes from the second path's input beam. Lots of words, but overall the same effect because the same beam splitter is used twice in the Michelson interferometer. Note also that a phase of $\pi$ might be added at the mirrors but that is symmetric across the two paths so it doesn't affect the overall interference pattern.

Short answer: beam splitter phases matter! For unitarity (reversibility) of the beam splitters, it is not possible to neglect these phases.

Comment: Thank you so much! So what I'm getting from this answer is that the beam splitter affects the phase of the waves itself? And the way it affects the phase is given by these matrices? If you have time (absolutely no pressure if not), would you be able to write out mathematically how the "red" and "blue" waves' phases transform through the michelson interferometer?

Comment: @JBatswani I'm not sure what notation you are used to, so I wanted to use mostly words - you are correct. The answer is also here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/503913/291677. The idea is not to use just "blue" and "red" but also label the paths. In the answer there, a reflection leads to an extra phase of $\pi$ but a transmission does not, so we get a different phase for "blue down" versus "blue left" for the outgoing light fields

Comment: Hi! Thank you SOO much! Everything just clicked! I've edited my question to have what I now believe the solution to be based on your answer. I would be eternally grateful if you could confirm that my understanding is now correct?

Comment: also do we need to use the matrix for when the light rays first enter the splitter (before they're reflected at all -- like the VERY first time they enter the splitter)? Why or why not?

Comment: @JBatswani yes, we need the matrix for the first time too. If you want it's better to write your answer as an answer here, that way it keeps the question-and-answer format of this forum (you're allowed to answer your own question!)

Answer (score 0):

So based on @Quantum Mechanic 's answer, I've tried to come up with an answer to the question. I will be using this revised diagram:
[image]

***Step 1: light exits source and hits beam splitter***

We will assume the light that exits the source will have amplitude $E_0$ (specifically, $\vec{E}_{source}(x,t)=E_0cos(kx- \omega t)\hat{e}_x$, but this specificity isn't too important to this answer). We can use the 50/50 beam splitter matrix equation to calculate the intensity of light that will hit the mirrors labelled "Arm 1" and "Arm 2" respectively *(this equation is inherent to the 50/50 beam splitter, and simply describes how the phase of the beams are affected by the splitter itself)*:
$$\begin{bmatrix}E_{received,\ arm\ 1}\\E_{received,\ arm\ 2}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}E_0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Note the use of $\begin{bmatrix}E_0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, where the second component is 0. This because all of the electric field is entering through **one** input port, not both. Computing this matrix multiplication, we arrive at the conclusion that
$$\begin{bmatrix}E_{received,\ arm\ 1}\\E_{received,\ arm\ 2}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}E_0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}E_0\end{bmatrix}$$
Knowing intensity goes as $I \propto E^2$, we can say
$$\begin{bmatrix}I_{received,\ arm\ 1}\\I_{received,\ arm\ 2}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}I_0\\\frac{1}{2}I_0\end{bmatrix}$$

***Step 2: light reflects off mirrors and hits beam splitter again***

When the light received by arms 1 and 2 reflect off the mirrors and arrive back at the beam splitter, note that we will be dealing with **two** incident electric fields -- I will call the one coming from one of the arms $E_a$ and the other $E_b$. It doesn't really matter which is which, but it does matter that one of the arms is movable -- that is, $d_1$ isn't always equal to $d_2$. **This is key**. Let's say $d_1$ is such that when light hits it, the light is reflected exactly in phase. That is,
$$E_{b}=E_{received,\ arm\ 2} cos(kx - wt) + E_{received,\ arm\ 2} cos(kx + wt) = 2E_{received,\ arm\ 2}cos(kx-wt) $$
However, let's say this is not the case for $d_2$. Specifically, let's say $d_2$ is such that when light bounces off the mirror, it is reflected with a new phase, $\varphi = kx + wt + \phi$.
$$E_{a}=E_{received,\ arm\ 1} cos(kx - wt) + E_{received,\ arm\ 1} cos(kx + wt + \phi) = 2E_{received,\ arm\ 2}cos(kx-wt)cos(\phi) = cos(\phi)E_b$$
Plugging this into our beam splitter matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}E_{received,\ det\ A}\\E_{received,\ det\ B}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}E_b\\E_bcos(\phi)\end{bmatrix}$$
We get that
$$\begin{bmatrix}E_{received,\ det\ A}\\E_{received,\ det\ B}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}E_b(1+cos(\phi))\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}E_b(1-cos(\phi))\end{bmatrix}$$
Finally, plugging in the subtle implicit conversion we did earlier: $E_b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}E_0$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}E_{received,\ det\ A}\\E_{received,\ det\ B}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}E_0(1+cos(\phi))\\\frac{1}{2}E_0(1-cos(\phi))\end{bmatrix}$$
This is our final solution. Note that this works in all of the observed cases, for example:

- $\phi = 2\pi n + \pi$: all of the light goes into detector B, and none into A
- $\phi = 2\pi n$: all of the goes into detector A, none into B
- $\phi = \frac{n \pi}{2}$: half of the light goes into detector A, half into detector B

Comment: @Quantum Mechanic